# Numerically solve an integral equation of the form $f(x)=f(0) - \frac{1}{2} \int_0^x f(x-y) \cdot (1-H(y)^2)\, dy.$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, numerical-methods, integral-equations, numerical-calculus

I have an integral equation of the form :

$$f(x)=f(0) - \frac{1}{2} \int_0^x f(x-y) \cdot (1-H(y)^2)\, dy.$$

I am looking for an efficient method to solve this integral equation, in particular I am interested in obtaining $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x)$?

The function $H(y)$ is defined by:
$$
H’(y)=1-H(y)-f(y),\qquad H(0) = 0.
$$

Comment: What function is H in this context?

Comment: I'm going to give you a guess that may not be helpful.  From the fundamental theorem of Calculus, if $f(x) - f(0) ~=~ \int_0^x g(t)dt$, then $f'(x) = g(x).$  For this particular problem formulation, I am confused at how to apply the theorem, but I suspect that the theorem is (somehow) pertinent.  Hope this helps.

Comment: @HenryLee: I made the problem more concrete.

Comment: This comment, which is from someone **unsophisticated** in Real Analysis,
may **not** be helpful.  Anyway... With respect to my previous comment, 
would it be possible for you to re-express or re-define $H(y)$ **and**
simultaneously remove the *occurrence* of $x$ from the integrand 
[i.e. $f(x - y)\cdots$]?  From my unsophisticated perspective,
having $x$ removed from the integrand, and (still) keeping $x$ outside of any specification of
$H(y)$ seems like it *might* be helpful.

Comment: @user2661923:  having this $x$ in the integral is indeed the main problem. I don't think that it really matters if this $x$ is in $f$ or $H$. The thing is that we have a convolution instead of a "normal" integral.. Convolutions do have good properties but I don't know any which I could use here.